# Lyx set Times New Roman 12 point font with 1 inch margins

Tags: lyx, margins, fontsize

Can someone please provide some help as to how I can set Times New Roman 12 point font with 1 inch margins in Lyx? For the margins, I went to Documents -> Settings -> Page Margins, and I set all of top, bottom, inner, and outer equal to 1 inch.

I'm still unclear about how to set 12 point font. My preamble is empty.

Comment: Is the margin size ok though? If so, take it out of the question as it is no longer an issue...

Comment: I think so, but just wanted to check that's the proper way. When including footnotes I can't tell if the margins are correct by visual inspection.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Document > Settings > Fonts and for "Base size" select "12". Then under Roman, select "Times Roman".

Comment: Do you know how I can select text midway through the document and set the size equal to 10? I'd like to make the text near the end of the paper size 10

Comment: @Zslice I'm not sure how to do that.